# Manipulating a complicated hashmap

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to implement a complicated data structure that looks like

```
Map<A,Set<B>> map = new HashMap<A,Set<B>>();
```

but I am not sure how to add content to this data structure. I am trying to do a

```
map.put(a,b);
```

but that doesn't help as it expects a set. The requirement I have needs to implement this data structure. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to add to the map?

Comment: I am trying to extract information from a webservice. The key A itself is a set- say projectname. And every project has a set of team members. so i need to map the project to another set. Hope I am making some sense here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `add` your element within the set contained in the hash map:

```
if (!map.containsKey(a)) {
    map.put(a, new Set<B>());
}
map.get(a).add(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to add a dependency to your project then [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has support for this. You need to use [SetMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html).

Comment: Um.  Guava team member here, I think you mean `SetMultimap`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the set and then add to it:

```
map.get(a).put(b);
```

You may also need to handle the special case that the set doesn't exist already.

```
Set<B> set = map.get(a);
if (set == null)
{
    set = new HashSet<B>();
    map.put(a, set);
}
set.put(b);
```